# Why my TOSCA script is not closing the browser?

Tags: automation, tosca

I am new to TOSCA, and completing my assessment for AS Level 1. Everything was fine until I reached Lesson 12 - Exercise 6. I followed all steps mentioned in the exercise and when I do "Run in Scratchbook" I get the below error.

Screenshots of the code and error:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a asterix also before Demo.
Depending on the title of the page it could be a reason that the window was not found.
Can you share the exact titel of the window.

Also I would recommend using the Test Configuration Parameter "Browser" and define the Browser which should be automated.

Comment: Hello, thank you for  your response. I have tried adding * before Demo also, but it dint worked. Throws the same error in scratchbook.

Also, I have selected Browser as Edge.
Title of the page is "Demo Web Shop". 

Not sure why iam not allowed to add screenshots here

Answer (score 0):

By this time you would have figured the issue, but anyways i wanted to post this as no reply's posted on your question.

1. Make sure you have the the browser plug in installed- ex: for chrome plugin
2. Make sure Chrome is your default browser.